# d3 animated map: after zooming in, how to correctly project points when animation begins?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, zooming

I made a map of points over time in d3. It works great. I added zoom. That works too. However, they don't totally work together.

I figured out that when I call the function to draw the circles, I need to reset the projection. I have the scale adjusted correctly. So if you zoom in and press play, the circles are the right size.

They aren't in the right place, though, because I can't figure out what the `translate` part of the projection needs to be.

So if you zoom and pan, then play, you'll see something like this:
[image]

I would be very grateful if anyone could offer insight. My code's below, and here's also a Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/HlMLKgARm0hgzLPN?open=lib%2Fscript.js
(The us.json file is too big to paste here, but is in plunker.)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/geo-albers-usa-territories@0.1.0/dist/geo-albers-usa-territories.js"></script>

  <style>
    body {
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
      font-size: 12px;
      color: #696969;
    }

    #play-button {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 130px;
      left: 50px;
      background: #333;
      padding-right: 26px;
      border-radius: 3px;
      border: none;
      color: white;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0 12px;
      width: 60px;
      cursor: pointer;
      height: 30px;
    }

    #play-button:hover {
      background-color: #696969;
    }

    .ticks {
      font-size: 10px;
    }

    .track,
    .track-inset,
    .track-overlay {
      stroke-linecap: round;
    }

    .track {
      stroke: #000;
      stroke-opacity: 0.3;
      stroke-width: 10px;
    }

    .track-inset {
      stroke: #dcdcdc;
      stroke-width: 8px;
    }

    .track-overlay {
      pointer-events: stroke;
      stroke-width: 50px;
      stroke: transparent;
      cursor: crosshair;
    }

    .handle {
      fill: #fff;
      stroke: #000;
      stroke-opacity: 0.5;
      stroke-width: 1.25px;
    }

    #zoom-buttons {
      position: absolute;
      margin-left: 10px;
      margin-top: 10px;
      padding: 5px;
      background: #fff;
    }

    #zoom-buttons button {
      background: #efefef;
      color: #231F20;
      border: 0;
      padding: 0;
      border-radius: 2px;
      width: 25px;
      height: 25px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="zoom-buttons">
    <button id="zoom-in">+</button>
    <button id="zoom-out">-</button>
  </div>
  <div id="vis">
    <button id="play-button">Play</button>
  </div>
  <script>

    var formatDateIntoYear = d3.timeFormat("%Y");
    var formatDate = d3.timeFormat("%b %Y");
    var parseDate = d3.timeParse("%m/%d/%y");

    var startDate = new Date("2004-11-01"),
      endDate = new Date("2017-04-01");

    var margin = { top: 50, right: 50, bottom: 0, left: 50 },
      width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
      height = 750 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var svg = d3.select("#vis")
      .append("svg")
      .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom);

    var projection = geoAlbersUsaTerritories.geoAlbersUsaTerritories()
      .scale(width + 100)
      .translate([width / 2, height / 2.2]);

    var path = d3.geoPath()
      .projection(projection);

    const zoom = d3.zoom()
      .scaleExtent([1, 10])
      .on('zoom', zoomed);

    svg.call(zoom)
    ////////// slider //////////

    var moving = false;
    var currentValue = 0;
    var targetValue = width;

    var playButton = d3.select("#play-button");

    var x = d3.scaleTime()
      .domain([startDate, endDate])
      .range([0, targetValue])
      .clamp(true);

    var slider = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "slider")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + height + ")");

    slider.append("line")
      .attr("class", "track")
      .attr("x1", x.range()[0])
      .attr("x2", x.range()[1])
      .select(function () { return this.parentNode.appendChild(this.cloneNode(true)); })
      .attr("class", "track-inset")
      .select(function () { return this.parentNode.appendChild(this.cloneNode(true)); })
      .attr("class", "track-overlay")
      .call(d3.drag()
        .on("start.interrupt", function () { slider.interrupt(); })
        .on("start drag", function () {
          currentValue = d3.event.x;
          update(x.invert(currentValue));
        })
      );

    slider.insert("g", ".track-overlay")
      .attr("class", "ticks")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + 18 + ")")
      .selectAll("text")
      .data(x.ticks(10))
      .enter()
      .append("text")
      .attr("x", x)
      .attr("y", 10)
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .text(function (d) { return formatDateIntoYear(d); });

    var handle = slider.insert("circle", ".track-overlay")
      .attr("class", "handle")
      .attr("r", 9);

    var label = slider.append("text")
      .attr("class", "label")
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .text(formatDate(startDate))
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (-25) + ")")


    ////////// map //////////

    var dataset;

    var layer1 = svg.append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    d3.json("us.json", function (error, us) {
      if (error) throw error;

      layer1.selectAll("path")
        .data(topojson.feature(us, us.objects.states).features)
        .enter().append("path")
        .attr("d", path)
        .attr("class", "feature")
        .attr("stroke", "#ccc")
        .attr("fill", "#fff")

      layer1.append("path")
        .datum(topojson.mesh(us, us.objects.states, function (a, b) { return a !== b; }))
        .attr("class", "mesh")
        .attr("d", path)
        .attr('fill', 'none')

    });

    var plot = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "plot")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    let zoomScale = 1; // initial zoom level

    d3.csv("circles.csv", prepare, function (data) {
      dataset = data;
      drawPlot(dataset);

      playButton
        .on("click", function () {
          var button = d3.select(this);
          if (button.text() == "Pause") {
            moving = false;
            clearInterval(timer);
            button.text("Play");
          } else {
            moving = true;
            timer = setInterval(step, 100);
            button.text("Pause");
          }
          console.log("Slider moving: " + moving);
        })
    })

    function prepare(d) {
      d.id = d.id;
      d.date = parseDate(d.date);
      return d;
    }

    function step() {
      update(x.invert(currentValue));
      currentValue = currentValue + (targetValue / 151);
      if (currentValue > targetValue) {
        moving = false;
        currentValue = 0;
        clearInterval(timer);
        // timer = 0;
        playButton.text("Play");
        console.log("Slider moving: " + moving);
      }
    }

    function drawPlot(data) {

      console.log('zoom scale', zoomScale)

      // update projection based on zoom
      projection = geoAlbersUsaTerritories.geoAlbersUsaTerritories()
        .scale((width + 100) * zoomScale) // this works
        .translate([width / 2, height / 2.2]) // what does this need to be?

      var locations = plot.selectAll(".location")
        .data(data);

      locations.enter()
        .append("circle")
        .attr("class", "location")
        .attr('cx', d => projection([d.lat, d.lng])[0])
        .attr('cy', d => projection([d.lat, d.lng])[1])
        .style("fill", '#333')
        .style("stroke", '#111')
        .style("opacity", 0.5)
        .attr("r", 3)
        .transition()
        .duration(400)
        .attr("r", 8)

      locations.exit()
        .remove();
    }

    function update(h) {
      handle.attr("cx", x(h));
      label
        .attr("x", x(h))
        .text(formatDate(h));

      var newData = dataset.filter(d => d.date < h)
      drawPlot(newData);
    }

    function zoomed() {

      zoomScale = d3.event.transform.k

      d3.zoomIdentity
        .scale(zoomScale)

      layer1
        .selectAll('path') // To prevent stroke width from scaling
        .attr('transform', d3.event.transform);

      plot
        .selectAll('circle')
        .attr('transform', d3.event.transform);

      plot
        .selectAll('.city')
        .attr('transform', d3.event.transform);

    }

    d3.select('#zoom-in').on('click', function () {
      console.log('zoomin in')
      zoom.scaleBy(svg.transition().duration(750), 1.3);
    });

    d3.select('#zoom-out').on('click', function () {
      zoom.scaleBy(svg.transition().duration(750), 1 / 1.3);
    });

  </script>
</body>
```

circles.csv:

```
id,date,lng,lat
1,11/24/04,38.285973,-122.365474
2,03/22/05,38.285973,-122.365474
3,06/02/05,37.792949,-122.459974
4,06/14/05,37.909155,-122.6518833333
5,07/01/05,33.631724,-117.950935
6,08/31/05,33.631724,-117.950935
7,09/01/05,34.039715,-118.888678
8,10/01/05,37.9217562781,-121.9406676292
9,11/14/05,34.039466,-118.579902
10,12/09/05,37.703584,-122.432026
11,02/14/06,38.38033,-123.08087
12,04/06/06,34.045192,-118.940949
13,05/26/06,34.045192,-118.940949
14,06/14/06,37.824757,-122.201442
15,07/07/06,37.816214,-122.210626
16,08/03/06,37.815468,-122.193975
17,09/14/06,37.822113,-122.195606
18,10/25/06,37.814383,-122.184705
19,11/20/06,37.822113,-122.195606
20,12/21/06,37.814383,-122.184705
21,01/23/07,37.31874272,-122.18163484
22,01/30/07,37.5738,-122.471
23,02/25/07,37.5738,-122.471
24,03/16/07,39.044386,-122.534122
25,04/13/07,39.044386,-122.534122
26,05/24/07,34.038791,-118.874559
27,06/16/07,37.31874272,-122.18163484
28,07/23/07,37.27148803,-122.15488797
29,08/13/07,37.32495478,-122.17827938
30,09/06/07,37.31874272,-122.18163484
31,10/19/07,34.125873,-118.707833
32,11/12/07,37.593929,-122.515068
33,12/11/07,37.593929,-122.515068
34,01/01/08,34.086431,-118.704786
35,02/06/08,37.005294,-121.683883
36,03/01/08,37.005294,-121.683883
37,04/01/08,34.038826,-118.875761
38,06/17/08,37.324748,-122.402458
39,07/03/08,37.324748,-122.402458
40,09/18/08,38.1186745227,-122.9507392645
41,10/08/08,37.91733,-122.335
42,11/19/08,37.8963,-122.355
43,12/18/08,37.4872,-121.929
44,01/20/09,34.040533,-118.891725
45,02/13/09,37.30647158,-122.17003327
46,03/20/09,37.30647158,-122.17003327
47,04/10/09,37.741558075,-122.4431838989
48,07/20/09,37.7649307251,-122.4374237061
49,08/10/09,37.502882,-122.478332
50,09/15/09,37.502882,-122.478332
51,10/19/09,37.9058615694,-122.6426225665
52,11/06/09,37.9058615694,-122.6426225665
53,12/17/09,37.4061431885,-122.2400054932
54,02/16/10,39.21226,-123.173217
55,03/14/10,37.895213,-122.031581
56,04/14/10,37.4225234985,-122.1740188599
57,05/05/10,38.601578,-121.138257
58,06/19/10,37.063256,-121.208691
59,07/01/10,37.67334,-122.408981
60,08/24/10,37.67334,-122.408981
61,09/01/10,37.754429,-122.136554
62,10/19/10,37.754429,-122.136554
63,11/06/10,38.5835812168,-122.699008584
64,12/27/10,37.548524,-122.505283
65,01/18/11,37.548524,-122.505283
66,02/22/11,37.919418335,-122.494720459
67,03/11/11,37.27148803,-122.15488797
68,04/26/11,37.27148803,-122.15488797
69,05/16/11,38.927165,-122.986536
70,07/14/11,38.771485,-121.042486
71,09/19/11,38.719269,-120.991916
72,11/16/11,37.27148803,-122.15488797
73,03/28/12,37.27148803,-122.15488797
74,04/19/12,38.593377,-121.462526
75,05/04/12,37.27148803,-122.15488797
76,07/19/12,37.27148803,-122.15488797
77,08/10/12,38.589829,-121.455835
78,09/16/12,34.099758,-118.711652
79,10/21/12,37.6951599121,-122.4476928711
80,11/15/12,37.8140938,-122.1833
81,12/03/12,37.19563508,-121.94371251
82,01/15/13,37.909155,-122.6518833333
83,03/24/13,37.19563508,-121.94371251
84,04/17/13,37.727423,-122.481812
85,05/13/13,37.8577162003,-122.5106131314
86,06/07/13,38.5785140991,-122.6990890503
87,07/03/13,37.281701,-120.862655
88,08/23/13,38.200491,-122.962797
89,09/22/13,37.6238162908,-122.1350258589
90,10/23/13,32.550129,-117.102812
91,11/14/13,32.548826,-117.101935
92,12/06/13,32.547429,-117.10247
93,02/04/14,38.6128130576,-122.7812719345
94,04/15/14,38.5835711527,-122.6989656687
95,07/03/14,37.4002395942,-122.2135899068
96,08/05/14,38.6361160278,-122.858757019
97,09/19/14,36.5,-119
98,10/28/14,36.5,-119
99,11/05/14,35.272334,-120.650649
100,12/19/14,37.8826501667,-122.5498195
101,02/06/15,37.8826501667,-122.5498195
102,03/01/15,33.570829,-117.551149
103,04/10/15,37.053838,-122.13295
104,05/18/15,37.900347,-122.024344
105,06/29/15,38.726416,-123.041826
106,08/20/15,39.3925,-123.648889
107,09/19/15,33.171683,-117.109108
108,10/22/16,37.9372660312,-122.1399235725
109,12/13/16,39.155156,-121.564922
110,02/16/17,32.825965,-117.053016
111,03/24/17,37.215688703,-122.0270562172
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally figured this out after banging my head against the wall for a while.

Working Plunker here:
https://plnkr.co/edit/LnISm6YJp1A5HFPT?open=lib%2Fscript.js

What I needed to do was not create a new projection, but instead transform the circles as they're created to account for current x,y postion based on any panning, and also transform scale based on any zooming.

Code is below along with some comments, should this prove helpful for anyone:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/geo-albers-usa-territories@0.1.0/dist/geo-albers-usa-territories.js"></script>

    <style>
        body {
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            font-size: 12px;
            color: #696969;
        }

        #play-button {
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 130px;
            left: 50px;
            background: #333;
            padding-right: 26px;
            border-radius: 3px;
            border: none;
            color: white;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0 12px;
            width: 60px;
            cursor: pointer;
            height: 30px;
        }

        #play-button:hover {
            background-color: #696969;
        }

        .ticks {
            font-size: 10px;
        }

        .track,
        .track-inset,
        .track-overlay {
            stroke-linecap: round;
        }

        .track {
            stroke: #000;
            stroke-opacity: 0.3;
            stroke-width: 10px;
        }

        .track-inset {
            stroke: #dcdcdc;
            stroke-width: 8px;
        }

        .track-overlay {
            pointer-events: stroke;
            stroke-width: 50px;
            stroke: transparent;
            cursor: crosshair;
        }

        .handle {
            fill: #fff;
            stroke: #000;
            stroke-opacity: 0.5;
            stroke-width: 1.25px;
        }

        #zoom-buttons {
            position: absolute;
            margin-left: 10px;
            margin-top: 10px;
            padding: 5px;
            background: #fff;
        }

        #zoom-buttons button {
            background: #efefef;
            color: #231F20;
            border: 0;
            padding: 0;
            border-radius: 2px;
            width: 25px;
            height: 25px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="zoom-buttons">
        <button id="zoom-in">+</button>
        <button id="zoom-out">-</button>
    </div>
    <div id="vis">
        <button id="play-button">Play</button>
    </div>
    <script>

        var formatDateIntoYear = d3.timeFormat("%Y");
        var formatDate = d3.timeFormat("%b %Y");
        var parseDate = d3.timeParse("%m/%d/%y");

        var startDate = new Date("2004-11-01"),
            endDate = new Date("2017-04-01");

        var margin = { top: 50, right: 50, bottom: 0, left: 50 },
            width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
            height = 750 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

        var svg = d3.select("#vis")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
            .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom);

        var projection = geoAlbersUsaTerritories.geoAlbersUsaTerritories()
            .scale(width + 100)
            .translate([width / 2, height / 2.2]);

        var path = d3.geoPath()
            .projection(projection);

        const zoom = d3.zoom()
            .scaleExtent([1, 10])
            .on('zoom', zoomed);

        svg.call(zoom)
        ////////// slider //////////

        var moving = false;
        var currentValue = 0;
        var targetValue = width;

        var playButton = d3.select("#play-button");

        var x = d3.scaleTime()
            .domain([startDate, endDate])
            .range([0, targetValue])
            .clamp(true);

        var slider = svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "slider")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + height + ")");

        slider.append("line")
            .attr("class", "track")
            .attr("x1", x.range()[0])
            .attr("x2", x.range()[1])
            .select(function () { return this.parentNode.appendChild(this.cloneNode(true)); })
            .attr("class", "track-inset")
            .select(function () { return this.parentNode.appendChild(this.cloneNode(true)); })
            .attr("class", "track-overlay")
            .call(d3.drag()
                .on("start.interrupt", function () { slider.interrupt(); })
                .on("start drag", function () {
                    currentValue = d3.event.x;
                    update(x.invert(currentValue));
                })
            );

        slider.insert("g", ".track-overlay")
            .attr("class", "ticks")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + 18 + ")")
            .selectAll("text")
            .data(x.ticks(10))
            .enter()
            .append("text")
            .attr("x", x)
            .attr("y", 10)
            .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
            .text(function (d) { return formatDateIntoYear(d); });

        var handle = slider.insert("circle", ".track-overlay")
            .attr("class", "handle")
            .attr("r", 9);

        var label = slider.append("text")
            .attr("class", "label")
            .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
            .text(formatDate(startDate))
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (-25) + ")")


        ////////// map //////////

        var dataset;

        var layer1 = svg.append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

        d3.json("us.json", function (error, us) {
            if (error) throw error;

            layer1.selectAll("path")
                .data(topojson.feature(us, us.objects.states).features)
                .enter().append("path")
                .attr("d", path)
                .attr("class", "feature")
                .attr("stroke", "#ccc")
                .attr("fill", "#fff")

            layer1.append("path")
                .datum(topojson.mesh(us, us.objects.states, function (a, b) { return a !== b; }))
                .attr("class", "mesh")
                .attr("d", path)
                .attr('fill', 'none')

        });

        var plot = svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "plot")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

        // define initial event transform
        let zoomScale = 1,
            panX = 0,
            panY = 0

        d3.csv("circles.csv", prepare, function (data) {
            dataset = data;
            drawPlot(dataset);

            playButton
                .on("click", function () {
                    var button = d3.select(this);
                    if (button.text() == "Pause") {
                        moving = false;
                        clearInterval(timer);
                        button.text("Play");
                    } else {
                        moving = true;
                        timer = setInterval(step, 100);
                        button.text("Pause");
                    }
                })
        })

        function prepare(d) {
            d.id = d.id;
            d.date = parseDate(d.date);
            return d;
        }

        function step() {
            update(x.invert(currentValue));
            currentValue = currentValue + (targetValue / 151);
            if (currentValue > targetValue) {
                moving = false;
                currentValue = 0;
                clearInterval(timer);
                playButton.text("Play");
            }
        }

        function drawPlot(data) {

            var locations = plot.selectAll(".location")
                .data(data);

            //transform circles based on pan and zoom
            locations.enter()
                .append("circle")
                .attr('transform', "translate(" + panX + "," + panY + ") scale(" + zoomScale + ")")
                .attr("class", "location")
                .attr('cx', d => projection([d.lat, d.lng])[0])
                .attr('cy', d => projection([d.lat, d.lng])[1])
                .style("fill", '#333')
                .style("stroke", '#111')
                .style("opacity", 0.5)
                .attr("r", 3)
                .transition()
                .duration(400)
                .attr("r", 8)

            locations.exit()
                .remove();
        }

        function update(h) {
            handle.attr("cx", x(h));
            label
                .attr("x", x(h))
                .text(formatDate(h));

            var newData = dataset.filter(d => d.date < h)
            drawPlot(newData);
        }

        function zoomed() {

            // update global transform properties so that new circles know where to go and how large to be
            zoomScale = d3.event.transform.k,
                panX = d3.event.transform.x,
                panY = d3.event.transform.y

            d3.zoomIdentity
                .scale(zoomScale)

            layer1
                .selectAll('path') // To prevent stroke width from scaling
                .attr('transform', d3.event.transform);

            plot
                .selectAll('circle')
                .attr('transform', d3.event.transform);

            plot
                .selectAll('.city')
                .attr('transform', d3.event.transform);

        }

        d3.select('#zoom-in').on('click', function () {
            zoom.scaleBy(svg.transition().duration(750), 1.3);
        });

        d3.select('#zoom-out').on('click', function () {
            zoom.scaleBy(svg.transition().duration(750), 1 / 1.3);
        });

    </script>
</body>
```